# Python Pandas add time in hours with date

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Hi I have this piece of code. I want to add date and specific time in hours and seconds together. But it results in this error: TypeError: dtype datetime64[ns] cannot be converted to timedelta64[ns]

These are my data:

```
#converting dates in 'string' to 'date' data type
#It is written in this format: 18.04.2017
df['Start Date']=df['Start Date'].astype('datetime64[ns]')

#converting times in 'string' to 'date' data type
#It is written in this format: 17:30
df['Start Time']=df['Start Time'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

What I am trying to do:

```
df['Start'] = df['Start Date'] + df['Start Time']
```

this results in this error: TypeError: dtype datetime64[ns] cannot be converted to timedelta64[ns]

#my expected result is this:

```
18.04.2017 17:30
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df['Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start Date'] + ' ' + df['Start Time'])
```